# How to implement search in this?

Tags: c++, search

I have handled the choice 1 satisfactorily all the others are up in the air. 
I have appended the new books to the end of the file, however i have no way to search a query amongst existing books. Neither do I have the proper code to handle issuing a book and removing it from records and it to the students.txt file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int choice;
cout<<endl<<endl<<"       ***************|Central Library Welcomes you|***************       "<<endl<<endl<<endl;
cout<<"       What would you like to do today:"<<endl<<endl;
cout<<"       1. Add a new Title."<<endl;
cout<<"       2. Search."<<endl;
cout<<"       3. Issue a book."<<endl;
cout<<"       4. Return a book."<<endl;
cout<<"       5. Student records."<<endl<<endl;
cout<<"       Please enter your query here:";
cin>>choice;
cin.ignore();

//for adding a new record. Works Fine. So far. I have added the app mode so that it enters new records at the end rather than deleting the whole file.
if (choice==1){
cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
cout<<"       Please enter the name of the book."<<endl;
string name;
cout<<"       ";
getline(cin, name);
cout<<endl<<"       Please enter the name of the author."<<endl;
string author;
cout<<"       ";
getline(cin, author);
ofstream addbook;
addbook.open("library.txt", ios::app);
addbook<<"NAME: "<<name<<endl<<"AUTHOR: "<<author<<endl<<endl;
addbook.close();
}


if (choice==2){
string search;
ifstream openFile;
openFile.open("library.txt");
cout<<endl<<"       Please enter the Keyword you will like to search for."<<endl;
bool isFound = 0;
cout<<"       ";
getline(cin, search);
if (openFile.is_open())
{
    while (!openFile.eof())
    {

    //The search should go here. I want to return the whole record if the search was successful. 


    openFile.close();
}
}
}
if (choice == 3){
    ifstream issuebook;
    issuebook.open("library.txt");
    cout<<endl<<"       Please enter you name."<<endl;
    string sName;
    cout<<"       ";
    getline(cin, sName);
    cout<<"       Please eneter the name of the book you will like to issue."<<endl;
    string bookFind;
    cout<<"       ";
    getline(cin, bookFind);
    //here we have to find the book in the file and remove its records from library file. 

    issuebook.close();
}
//CHOICE 4. This will take the name of the author and book and add it back to the library.txt file.
if (choice == 4){
    string returnedBook;
    string authorName;
    cout<<endl<<"       Please enter the name of the book you would like to return."<<endl;
    string name;
    cout<<"       ";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout<<endl<<"       Please enter the name of the author."<<endl;
    string author;
    cout<<"       ";
    getline(cin, author);
    ofstream addbook;
    addbook.open("library.txt", ios::app);
    addbook<<"NAME: "<<name<<endl<<"AUTHOR: "<<author<<endl<<endl;
    addbook.close();


}

if (choice == 5){
    ifstream studentRecords;
    studentRecords.open("student.txt");
    cout<<endl<<"       Enter the name of the student you will like to search for:"<<endl;
    string student;
    cout<<"       ";
    getline(cin, student);
    //Display the record of student.

    studentRecords.close();
}
}
```

Comment: what keeps you from writing the code? you have to tell us what is the problem

Comment: I cannot write the code that takes the search query from user output if that item is in the file and if it is then take the name of the book plus the number of times it occurs in the file.

Comment: that is for choice 2. For choice 3 I don't exactly know how to take the book input by the user and delete its record from the file and it to the books borrowed part os student.txt file.

Comment: and why you cannot do this ? Is your text editor broken? ... seriously you have to ask a specific question, otherwise the only way to help you would be to write the full code for you

Comment: I dont know how. That is the simple answer. I havenever done file handling before this.

Comment: you dont search in the file, but you have to keep a list of the books in memory, e.g. a `std::vector<Book>`. First of all you should define a data structure for the books

Comment: i have just completed my first semester of study so this is where i am at

Comment: imho the first thing you should learn in c++ is how you can define your own data structure, actually that is what it was made for

Comment: I will write an answer, if the question wont get closed in the meantime...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is define a data structure for the books. Something like:

```
struct Book {
    std::string name;
    std::string author;
    std::string ISBN;
}
```

Then you can overload the input and output operators

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream &o, const Book& b) { 
     o << b.name;
     o << b.author;
     o << b.ISBN;
     return output;            
}
```

and

```
std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& in, Book& b ) { 
     in >> b.name;
     in >> b.author;
     in >> b.ISBN;
     return in;            
}
```

Once you have this you can use any input stream or output stream (e.g. `std::cout`/`std::cin` or an `ifstream`) to read/write a book, e.g.

```
Book b;
std::cin >> b;
std::cout << b << std::endl;
```

Actually your question is too broad and I can only give you some hints. You will have to learn all this from your lectures or some books. However, if I was a teacher, the above is the very first thing I would teach about C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ups, fixed